# Insert characters such as "&" or "%" in a MySQL query

Tags: php, mysql, database, character

I'd like to insert special character ("&" or "%" for example) in a query, but everytime I try, the string I have inserted gets cutted.

For instance, if I type "Bolliger&Mabillard is a rollercoaster manufacturer", I just get "Bolliger".

The code I'm using to insert the string into the database is:

```
include("connect.php");

$query="insert into news (title, body) values('About', 'Bolliger&Mabillard is a rollercoaster manufacturer');";
$run = mysql_query($query) or die ($query);
mysql_close();
```

What can I do?

Thanks!

Comment: whats the length of body eg varchar(xx)?

Comment: its varchar(999), while the character encoding its "latin1_swedish_ci"

Comment: show your code please

Comment: Actually, I insert the string through a javascript script:

<script type="text/javascript">
function save() 
{ 
 var title="About";
 var body="Bolliger&Mabillard is a rollercoaster manufacturer"; 
 window.open("http://www.example.com/add.php?title=" + title + "&body="+body);
} 
</script>

Comment: try adding $insertdata = mysql_real_escape_string($query)

Comment: sure, here's the code. add.php contains:

$title=$_GET['title'];
$body=$_GET['body'];

include("connect.php");
$query="insert into news (title, body) values('".$title."','".$body."');";
$run = mysql_query($query) or die ($query);
mysql_close();

Comment: Thank you, I tried to add $insertdata = mysql_real_escape_string($query) but it still doesn't work. I think that the error is caused by the javascript script because the "&" make it think that it has to pass another variable to add.php

Comment: Then delete this question and ask the real one instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$data1=mysql_real_escape_string("Bolliger&Mabillard is a rollercoaster manufacturer");
```

Answer (score 0):

May this will help you...

the shortest way is here... (using mysql predefined function)

```
<?php
    include("connect.php");
    $bodyData = "Bolliger&Mabillard%is a rollercoaster manufacturer";
    $bodyData = mysql_real_escape_string($bodyData);
    $query="insert into news (title, body) values('About', '".$bodyData."')";
    $run = mysql_query($query) or die ($query);
    mysql_close();
 ?>
```

or you can take longer way like below... (using your own function)

```
<?php
    include("connect.php");

    function xss($string)
        {
            return str_replace(
                            array('!','"','#','$','%','&',"'",'(',')','*','+',',','-','.','/',':',';','<','=','>','?','@','[','\\',']','^','_','{','|','}','~'),
                            array('\!','\"','\#','\$','\%','\&',"\'",'\(','\)','\*','\+','\,','\-','\.','\/','\:','\;','\<','\=','\>','\?','\@','\[','\\','\]','\^','\_','\{','\|','\}','\~'),
                            $string);
        }


    $bodyData = "Bolliger&Mabillard%is a rollercoaster manufacturer";
    $bodyData = xss($bodyData);
    $query="insert into news (title, body) values('About', '".$bodyData."')";
    $run = mysql_query($query) or die ($query);
    mysql_close();
    ?>
```

You will get result using this code...

```
 <?php
    include("connect.php");


    function xss_r($string)
        {
            return str_replace(
                            array('\!','\"','\#','\$','\%','\&',"\'",'\(','\)','\*','\+','\,','\-','\.','\/','\:','\;','\<','\=','\>','\?','\@','\[','\\','\]','\^','\_','\{','\|','\}','\~'),
                            array('!','"','#','$','%','&',"'",'(',')','*','+',',','-','.','/',':',';','<','=','>','?','@','[','\\',']','^','_','{','|','}','~'),
                            $string);
        }
    $last = 1; // here your id which is compare with id in database...
    $rs = mysql_query("select body from members where id = ".$last);
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($rs);
    echo xss_r($row['body']);
    mysql_close();
    ?>
```

Comment: Thank you very much Raghu! Anyway, I did a mistake when posting the question, I'm going to delete this one!

Comment: Don’t use your own function! Like in this case it’s still vulnerable to SQL injections. Use parameterized statements as provided by prepared statements.